# Magsafe light occasionally turns off while plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe

Every once in a while, the green light on my Magsafe adapter will turn off, but the computer will indicate that it's still running off of AC power. If I unplug the adapter from the computer and then plug it back in, it'll immediately light up again. Is this normal?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Apple's troubleshooting documentation: [Apple Portables: Troubleshooting MagSafe adapters](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1713)

I have a late-2011 MacBook Air, and I have never experienced this issue.

Comment: "Another indication of possible strain relief that is not always visible to the eye is intermittent charging or strange LED behavior. You can often verify this condition by wiggling the cable back and forth near the MagSafe connector and observing whether the LED indicator (which turns amber or green) flashes on or off depending on the position of the cord." I tried that and the light did turn back on, so that sounds like it could be the problem...though the cable doesn't show any visible signs of strain.